# Importing project-specific rc files in Neovim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Vim probably did this by default, whenever I invoke files from a project that has its own `.vimrc`s it's auto-sourced. Neovim, however, doesn't import `vimrc`s. How can I make Neovim scan and use project-specific configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't do that by default, you probably had `set exrc` in your `.vimrc`, see [`:h 'exrc'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27exrc%27).

As the doc says if you add `set exrc` to your vimrc you also probably want to add `set secure` ([`:h 'secure'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27secure%27)).

Both of these options are also available in neovim.

You may also want to have a look at [this Luc Hermitte's plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) which also allows to enable local configurations files with more options.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Does Neovim recognise all the original `vimrc`s, or do I have to change the file name?

Comment: Well their doc ([`:h 'exrc'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27exrc%27)) says `Enables the reading of .vimrc and .exrc in the current directory.` so I would say that either they read `.vimrc` and `.exrc` files _or_ they forgot to update the doc (but I doubt it is the case)

Comment: I'll make sure to try both. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, exrc was deprecated in Neovim shortly after this answer was published. https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5784

Comment: Setting exrc no longer supports execution of .vimrc, you've got to use a file named .nvim.lua, .nvimrc, or .exrc (as described by the current `:h 'exrc'`)